# Rounding/String Formatting Decimals in c#

Tags: c#, formatting

```
value.ToString("##0.00000%;(##0.00000%);0.00000%");
```

I'm having trouble deciphering how this is being formatted. Would it ever display a value above that would be .00001 lower than the correct rounding, or if the number would just to be truncated at 5 decimal places?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it rounds in the conventional way (e.g. 1-4 rounds down and 5-9 rounds up).

Comment: Hmm, okay. Right now we have a situation where this is producing a number that is .00001 less than a number from another source, however calculated in the same way, so I am convinced it is in the display, and I'm trying to find a situation where that would happen.

Comment: If your using floating point, you may encounter oddities due to its imprecision. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems for some details.

Comment: If you believe it is simply the display place breakpoints and see what the value is exactly.  You could also simply display the entire value I suppose.

Comment: How would I switch the format I had in the question, to perform bankers rounding instead?

Comment: Round the value yourself: `Math.Round( someValue , MidpointRounding.ToEven )` ... or write your own custom format provider.